# CSS animation not working with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have an image that only pop-ups up once every 7 days when the user switches the tab, then comes back to the page. I want that image to have animation that appears from the bottom of the page up the center of the viewport.

I have code in place that has the animation, but it is not working. I am not sure if it something needs to happen in my visibility change function, because at the moment, the window.load function is doing nothing.

When I inspect the image in the console and I untick and tick `top: "10vh"`, I can see the animation happen, but I need this to happen when the user switches tab and then comes back on the page.

**JS:**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  const popUp = document.getElementById("circle-parent");
  popUp.style.top = "10vh";
});


document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  // if (!cookieExists()) {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    popUp.style.display = "none";
  } else if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
    popUp.style.display = "block";
    // setCookie(cookieName);
  }
  //   }
  //  else {
  //   setCookie(uklFocusCookie)
  // }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
            <div id="circle-parent" class="circle-parent" style="display: none">
                <img id="circle" class="circle" src="assets/images/thanks_for_visiting_img.png">
                <img id="close-button" class="close-button" src="assets/images/close_green.png" onclick="handleButtonClick()">
                <img id="quotes-button" class="quotes-button" src="assets/images/btn.png" onclick="handleButtonClick()">
                <div class="background">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.circle-parent {
    position: fixed;
    left: calc(45% - 225px);
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0px;
    outline: none;
    top: 140vh;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Will this work for u

Comment: I'm just finishing a different task, then I will be taking a look at the CSS today, so I'll give it a go and let you know. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: was it useful or should I work on my code again

Answer (score 0):

### This will work fine in chrome and firefox.

I used blur and focus event of window object to give transition effect to the image class.
Blur event gets triggered when the document or the whole tab looses focus and Focus event occurs when the tab gets refocused.

#### The reason why the visibility change event isn't working is because when this event fires the user hasn't lost the focus from the page.So the tab change will not be detected here

### JS

```
    var popUp = document.getElementById("circle-parent");
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
popUp.style.display = "block";  
    popUp.style.top = "10vh";
  
});


window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
popUp.style.display = "none";
 
});
window.addEventListener('focus',function(){
popUp.style.display = "block";
});
```

### CSS

```
    .circle-parent {
      position: fixed;
      left: calc(45% - 225px);
      width: 550px;
      height: 550px;
      z-index: 1;
      right: 0px;
      outline: none;
      top: 140vh;
      transition: 0.4s;
      animation: show_pic 1s forwards 1;
    }

    @keyframes show_pic {
      from {
        transform: translateY(140vh);
      }
      to {
        transform: translateY(10vh);
      }
    }
```

### HTML

```
    <div class="image-wrapper">
            <div id="circle-parent" class="circle-parent" style="display: none">
                <img id="circle" class="circle" src="assets/images/thanks_for_visiting_img.png">
                <img id="close-button" class="close-button" src="assets/images/close_green.png" onclick="handleButtonClick()">
                <img id="quotes-button" class="quotes-button" src="assets/images/btn.png" onclick="handleButtonClick()">
                <div class="background">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```